# Burninate [news ticker] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [news-ticker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news-ticker) (x48) tag is not related to programming, has 1 follower, no one can really be "an expert" in it, and it cannot be the only tag for a valid question here on StackOverflow.

As such, shouldn't it be burninated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to programming when you program news tickers :) I also can't quite call it a meta tag even though it could encompass lots of different languages, libraries, frameworks, etc.

I think it's relevant enough to stay. I can't imagine ever using it in a tag search, but I can't discount that someone else would.

I don't know how those ticker people make it through their days .. all that ticking and ticking .. ugh.